# Increasing capacity of circular queue in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, queue, capacity

I am learning about queues and am trying to write a method to change the maximum capacity of a circular queue using a dynamic array.  This is what my code looks like right now.

```
void ArrayQueue::setCapacity(unsigned newCapacity){
if(newCapacity == 0 || newCapacity < this->getSize()){
    throw QueueException("setCapacity()", "invalid new capacity");
} else if(newCapacity != this->getSize()){
    Item * tempArray = new Item[newCapacity];
    for(unsigned i=0; i<newCapacity; i++){
        tempArray[i] = myArray[i];
    }
    Item * oldArray = myArray;
    myArray = tempArray;
    delete [] oldArray;
}
this->myCapacity = newCapacity;
}
```

However, when I decrease the capacity, I fail assertions to get the myFirst and myLast values.  I understand that I need to write code to account for a case in which the entries have wrapped around but am confused about how to do so.

The test I'm trying to pass has code as follows:

```
    ArrayQueue q5(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    q5.append(i+1);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    q5.remove();
}
assert( q5.getCapacity() == 10 );
assert( q5.getSize() == 3 );
assert( !q5.isEmpty() );
assert( !q5.isFull() );
assert( q5.getFirst() == 8 );
assert( q5.getLast() == 10 );

//reduce the capacity
q5.setCapacity(5);
assert( q5.getCapacity() == 5 );
assert( q5.getSize() == 3 );
assert( !q5.isEmpty() );
assert( !q5.isFull() );
assert( q5.getFirst() == 8 );
assert( q5.getLast() == 10 );
```

I'm passing my first set of assertions but the second getFirst assertion is failing.

Could you give me a pointer in the right direction?  Thanks.

Comment: your for loop is incorrect, `myArray[i]` will read out of bounds if you ever grow the queue.

Comment: If your ArrayQueue has a constructor that takes a capacity, you could have written this function a lot simpler than what you posted.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest rewriting this using the following:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
void ArrayQueue::setCapacity(unsigned newCapacity)
{
    if(newCapacity == 0 || newCapacity < this->getSize()){
        throw QueueException("setCapacity()", "invalid new capacity");
    ArrayQueue tempQ(newCapacity);
    for(unsigned i=0; i< capacity; i++)
        tempQ.append(myArray[i]);
    std::swap(myArray, tempQ.myArray);
    std::swap(capacity, tempQ.capacity);
    std::swap(size, tempQ.size);
}
```

How does this work?  Well, we create a temporary `ArrayQueue` with the necessary capacity.  Then all we do is copy the data to the temporary object.  After that we swap out the temporary object with `this`.

Done.

The temp object dies with the old data, and `this` is set with the new data.  This is a variation of the `copy/swap` idiom.  This requires a working destructor for `ArrayQueue` -- once you have that, then it becomes a piece of cake.

Note that if there are more member variables, they need to be swapped also.  I just swapped the ones that you posted.  I guessed you have a `size` member variable, so if you named it differently, then replace it with the name you used.  Bottom line -- swap everything out with the `tempQ`, and you should be ok.

If you don't know what `std::swap` does, it does what it says.  It just swaps the two items with each other -- nothing special, just convenient to just use a function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(unsigned i=0; i<newCapacity; i++){
    tempArray[i] = myArray[i];
}
```

If your new capacity is larger, then you will access myArray with invalid indices

Answer (score 0):

As best as I can figure out your question, you're referencing assertions thrown elsewhere, other than the code fragment that you posted. Since you have not posted the code that you find problematic, it's unlikely that anyone will give you an answer.

However, I do see a likely bug in the code fragment that you posted. Your code that increases the size of the array:

```
Item * tempArray = new Item[newCapacity];
for(unsigned i=0; i<newCapacity; i++){
    tempArray[i] = myArray[i];
}
Item * oldArray = myArray;
myArray = tempArray;
delete [] oldArray;
```

Let's say, for example, the old size of myArray was 20, and you increased it to 40.

You're going to allocate a new 40-element tempArray.

Then proceed to copy the first 40 elements from myArray to tempArray.

Undefined behavior.

Comment: I just updated my question with the code for the test that is failing.  In the assertion that's failing, I reduced the capacity.  The myFirst and myLast vlaues are correct with the original capacity but after halving the capacity, they don't work.  The myFirst is 0 and the myLast is 5 which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @TheFaceOfBoe Does this set the capacity to 10? `ArrayQueue q5(10);`  If so, my initial comment still stands -- you can code setCapacity in a much more simple way than what you wrote.  So simple that it would be very difficult, if not impossible for there to be an error.  I would post an answer, but need confirmation that this constructor sets the capacity...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, that does set the capacity to 10.  However, I'm not sure what easier way you're thinking of.  I'd still need to allocate a new array and copy each element into the new array which is what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: @TheFaceOfBoe See my answer below.  Use what has been coded already to your advantage, and that is what the answer I gave is doing...